# WordPress site behind Apache reverse proxy keeps redirecting to localhost

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, podman, podman-compose

I am trying to deploy a containerized Wordpress on a production server using podman-compose (works similar to docker-compose). The web service is exposed on port 8080 on the host. Then, I'm leveraging Apache's ProxyPass directive to create a reverse proxy and send requests to localhost:8080 where WordPress is being served, thus making WordPress available on http://example.com.
I successfully managed to migrate database and wordpress volumes to the server. The first problem I had was that WordPress stores localhost as `siteurl` and `home` in wpoptions so it will not work on the production server. After changing these values to example.com (my domain), IT KEEPS REDIRECTING to localhost. Insane!
Here's my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  web:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mypass
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 0
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wpnet
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6603:3306

    volumes:
      - wpdbvol:/var/lib/mysql

    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
    networks:
      - wpnet
volumes:
  wordpress: {}
  wpdbvol: {}

networks:
  wpnet: {}
```

And here's my reverse proxy configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

ProxyPass "/"  "https://localhost:8080"

#Allows modification of Location: headers from backend server to point to the reverse proxy
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://localhost:8080"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Might have another idea.

Comment: Not really. Still no progress :(

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your case might be that you are missing the `/` at the end of `ProxyPass`, `ProxyPassReverse` urls.

In my case I wanted to serve it on: https://example.com

So, What I did (on wordpress 5.8.1) was:

**1.** In the database (or ui directly) I had to update both `siteurl` and `home`  (no trailing `/` needed there)

```sql
update wp_options set option_value="https://example.com" where option_name in ("siteurl", "home");
```

**2.** Pasting also the reverse proxy settings for apache (`X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Port` are crucial settings):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/sslcert/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/sslcert/server.key"

   ProxyRequests Off
   KeepAlive Off
   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   # These are required for https reverse proxy to work with wordpress  (They are read from `wp-config.php`)
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"   

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ErrorLog "logs/wordpress.revproxy-sslerror_log"
   CustomLog "logs/wordpress.revproxy-sslaccess_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Note:** In my case I have tested it with reverse-proxy being a service of docker-compose so in the above settings (of step **2**) instead of `http://localhost:8080/` I was using `http://wpcontainer/`. But in your case the above should work as is.

Comment: I added your settings to my httpd config and now I don't get redirected to localhost anymore, but the site loads only partially and it gives a lot of cross-site warnings in the browser log. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you changed both `siteurl` and `home`? Also maybe you can clear browser cache. If problem persists can you please send the url which causes the issue (copied from `devtools` `network` tab: F12)?

Comment: The "RequestHeader" did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot and more than likely won't work.

Maybe try defining `https://example.com` as your home url in the compose yml `environment` `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` settings.

```yml
services: 
  web:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mypass
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 0
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        
        /** define our home url */
        define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');

    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wpnet
```

This **might** force the wordpress installation to it's destination and stop it redirecting back to `localhost`.

---

Also when I was having issues getting [ngrok tunnelling](https://ngrok.com/docs#wordpress) to hit my local wordpress environment, I had to install the [Relative URL](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/) wordpress plugin which got my tunnel working.

Not sure if this is relevant to your question but might be worth installing [Relative URL](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/) plugin and seeing if this fixes your localhost redirect issue before trying the above `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` idea.

The plugin has not been updated in 2 years but still works fine with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Plugin is literally 20 lines of php which I guess could be dropped into your functions.

[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) allows me to access my local docker compose wordpress environment through a https protocol url like `http://example.ngrok.io/`, which is handy for me to handle local webhook response callbacks (which I use with stripe).

Comment: Although most of the installation issues are gone after this change, still requesting homepage drops the browser to localhost.

Comment: Hmmm not really sure man, hope you work it out.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that encounters this with WP running over ssl:

If you have Nginx as a proxy for Apache, the `HTTPS` global has to be explicitly set in PHP (preferable in wp-config.php) with `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'On';`, otherwise WP will keep redirecting, because Nginx runs on ssl, but Apache isn't and WP only sees the Apache environment.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, but i hit on the same problem while using nginx and apache reverse proxy. Solution was very easy , but on the same very hard to find root cause. Solution:

nginx config-> add $request_uri to the proxy_pass

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;

More information here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirect-loop-with-wordpress-on-apache-with-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-https-on-ubuntu-16

Comment: In general, I think the fix is easier for nginx